# CSS inner shadow without box-shadow property

Tags: css

I have some clip-path polygon elements, some are more complex but I'll use a hexagon here.

```css
.hex{
    width: 120px;
    aspect-ratio: 1.1547005 / 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    clip-path: polygon(
                    0 50%,
                    25% 0,
                    75% 0,
                    100% 50%,
                    75% 100%,
                    25% 100%
    );
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="hex">I have<br />five sides.</div>
```

**Clarification: inset shadow**

Box-shadow won't work because it sticks to the bounding box, not the clip-path.

Even with a simple shape like the hexagon, I cannot figure out how to get the box-shadow property to handle the angles, I don't think it's possible.

filter:drop-shadow doesn't handle inset and also can't work outside the clip-path.

Short of replicating my clip-paths on child elements and offsetting them with a background color/gradient... is there a straightforward CSS solution for this I'm missing?

Comment: *straightforward* not but we can use a lot of techniques to simulate the specific shadow you want

Comment: When you say inset shadow, how should it look?  Currently the hexagon is black, so I'm not sure what you desired outcome would look like.  Would it be white with an inset shadow, or a white shadow insetting the black, or do you just mean inset, as in a normal box-shadow but following the clip-path?

Comment: @PsiKai normal as possible inset box-shadow following the clip-path

Comment: I don't think I can give you the answer you're looking for, but if you use an `::after` element, you can inherit the clip path.  This will work if you are setting clip-path dynamically.  Good luck!

Comment: @PsiKai Actually... that's a pretty handy thing to know. I would not have thought of that! Thanks!

Comment: A compromise could be using a radial gradient. possible example to play with :  `background:radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 30% , red 90%) #000;`

Comment: @G-Cyrillus for the hex example, yeah sorta. For more complex polygons not so much. It is possible to construct sections of layers of background gradients to do this, but that would be absolutely insane for anything more than the most basic cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if you wrap your element to a parent div and add a `drop-shadow` to it.

`html`:

```html
<div class="shadow">
  <div class="hex">I have<br />five sides.</div>
</div>
```

`css`:

```css
.hex{
    width: 120px;
    aspect-ratio: 1.1547005 / 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    clip-path: polygon(
                    0 50%,
                    25% 0,
                    75% 0,
                    100% 50%,
                    75% 100%,
                    25% 100%
    );
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}

.shadow {
  filter: drop-shadow(-1px 6px 3px rgba(50, 50, 0, 0.5));
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kongallis/0uajpbs8/2/

For more read: https://css-tricks.com/using-box-shadows-and-clip-path-together/

Comment: That's good information, but the question is for inner shadows